# Pre build error cannot solve in my react native app

Tags: react-native, deployment, build, mern, prebuild

This is my first app. I cannot resolve errors. Please help me.

error show in expo site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the package-lock.json.
Then run the command again eas build -p android